# Запретить повторную отправку POST Yii2

Tags: yii2, post

Для примера есть такой код

```
public function actionCategory(){
    $this->layout='content';

    $model=Category::find()->all();

    $item=new Category();

    if ($item->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
        if ($item->save()){
            Notification::widget([
                'type' => 'success',
                'message' => 'Категория добавлена',
            ]);

            return;
        }
    }

    return $this->render('category', ['model'=>$model, 'item'=>$item]);
}
```

Все работает, но есть одна проблема. Если обновить страницу еще раз - категория снова добавится.

Как убрать повторную отправку POST?

Comment: Yii тут не при чем. Используйте редирект на ту же самую страницу после обработки данных.

Comment: спасибо, я что то затупил :)

Comment: Вообще, есть ещё способы, но вам предложили самый простой и эффективный. Даже не знаю, будете ли вы удалять свой вопрос или захочет кто-то написать полноценный ответ, но в двух словах. Видели как у формы бывает капча? При этом один раз отправил форму -- капча уже другая. Можно именно подписывать форму некоторой подписью и после обработки POST-запроса удалять выданную подпись, чтобы нельзя было обработать дважды.

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов два.

1. Подписываете веб-форму (можно [почитать у Котерова как он это реализовывал в 2005 году в своей библиотеке](http://dklab.ru/lib/HTML_MetaForm/))
2. После обработки запроса делаете редирект

Второй явно проще, первый бывает достаётся из коробки.